# Android sms application read sent sms

Tags: java, android, sms, android-handler, mms

As the default sms application, I can easily read all messages that come in, then I found on the forms how to write the sms log, but my sent sms, from my app or I assume another app I still cant read, and therefore cannot write to the outbox uri.

Any Ideas how I can do this and properly implement this with a normal sms app?

I don't need mms support to to really deal with those, but if anyone knows anything on top of this also, help would be appreciated!

If you want any of my code let me know! (java btw)

android studio config:
compileSdk 31
minSdk 28
targetSdk 31
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

I have tried using the listener on

```
<service
            android:name=".test.sms_test_owner"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

and

```
<activity android:name=".test.sms_test_owner$test"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but dont get any callbacks when my app sends a message; is this intended and works for other apps, or how do I deal with both cases?

messages sent with:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumberToSend, null, smsTextToSend, null, null);
```

for example from another app